# Selenium - Wait until returned javascript script value match value

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I need to wait until the result of a javascript match a string or a boolean value.

With this javascript:

```
document.getElementById('video_html5').seeking;
```

I get a "false" / "true" value, and i need to wait until the value is "false", so I'm sure that the video is not seeking, but I only found the way to wait for a javascript command value and not the way to check that the value matches some text.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return document.getElementById('video_html5').seeking;"));
```

Because in some cases I get a string other than boolean and need to compare those strings.

I have found how to do it in Ruby but not in Java:

```
wait_element = @wait.until { @driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('vid1_html5_api_Shaka_api').seeking;").eql? false }
```

Comment: Would this work? `jsReturnsValue("document.getElementById('video_html5').seeking === 'false' ? 'true' : undefined;")` It'll compare the value directly in the JavaScript, returning `undefined` if seeking is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your own custom expected conditions.

```
public class MyCustomConditions {

  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> myCustomCondition() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
          .executeScript("return document.getElementById('video_html5').seeking === 'string_value' || ... ");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

And then in your tests you can use the condition as follows.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(MyCustomConditions.myCustomCondition());
```

Comment: The thing is that I prefer some sort of universal way to do it, because i need to make many comparisons of strings with the javascript results, so i would prefer to not having to add a customCondition for every comparison, if possible.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a single condition with generic logic and then pass specific parameters as needed.

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to do it (where `command` is the JavaScript you want to run with `webdriver` in `timeout` seconds):

```
public Object executeScriptAndWaitOutput(WebDriver driver, long timeout, final String command) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
  wait.withMessage("Timeout executing script: " + command);

  final Object[] out = new Object[1];
  wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
      try {
        out[0] = executeScript(command);
      } catch (WebDriverException we) {
        log.warn("Exception executing script", we);
        out[0] = null;
      }
      return out[0] != null;
    }
  });
  return out[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did the following and worked, getting ideas from different answers:

```
public Boolean checkStateSeeking() throws InterruptedException {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        Boolean seekingState = (Boolean) js
                .executeScript("return document.getElementById('vid1_html5').seeking;");

        while (seekingState) {
            // System.out.println(seekingState);
            seekingState = (Boolean) js
                    .executeScript("return document.getElementById('vid1_html5').seeking;");
        }

        return seekingState;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting ideas for all the answers I create a function to wait for an element to change each and waiting N seconds, using the xpath of the element and the expected value.

```
 public static String checkValueChanged(WebDriver driver, String expectedValue, String path, int waitTime) throws InterruptedException {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String elementValue = (String) js
            .executeScript("return document.evaluate(\""+path+"\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value;");

    while (!(elementValue.equals(expectedValue)) && (waitTime>0)) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        waitTime--;
        elementValue = (String) js
                .executeScript("return document.evaluate(\""+path+"\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value;");
    }
    return elementValue;
}
```